# AVPlayerItemStatus failed while AVPlayerStatus readyToPlay

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am attempting to simply play a video from a URL. I have done this many times before however currently it is failing. Here is the code I am using to load the URL and play the video:

```
func prepareWith(url: URL) {
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    avPlayer?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    avPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [], context: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { _ in
        self.avPlayer = nil
    })

    videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    videoLayer.frame = frame
    videoLayer.masksToBounds = false
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let key = keyPath {
        if key == "status", let player = avPlayer {
            if player.status == AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay {
                layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that this could be due to the fact that iOS limits to 4 AVPlayer instances; however, I changed the AVPlayer so it is initially nil and set it to nil again once it has finished playing. Therefore, I don't believe that this is the issue. When I print the current item's error, I get:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x61800005aeb0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12893 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12893), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Comment: only two questions: a) are you using more players at once? b) you add layer when data are ready, but if You are in a view and start loading, and user exits, you should stop loading, kill players and so on.. so better to add layers at start. (definitively a design issue)

Comment: I believe that at the moment of this error, there should only be the one AVPlayer instantiated.